# Bol Retailer API: Exporting Offer File using Python and API Version 9

Tags: python, bad-request

I am not able to export an Offers File when I try to fetch it via Python Code. I am trying to use the Bol. com API V9 and request a list of all offers.

```
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.retailer.V9+json',
    "Content-Type": 'application/vnd.retailer.V9+json',
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + f"{access_token}"
}
params = {
    "format": "CSV",
}

url = "https://api.bol.com/retailer/offers/export"
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=params)
```

Do you have an idea what I am missing out? Or is their API just buggy at this point?
The POST Call gives me a result which looks like that:

> Status-Code: 400
> {
> "type" : "https://api.bol.com/problems",
> "title" : "Bad Request",
> "status" : 400,
> "detail" : "The supplied accept header media type is not supported.",
> "host" : "Instance-106",
> "instance" : "https://api.bol.com/retailer/offers/export?format=CSV"
> }

IMO the "Accept" Header looks absolutely fine according to their documentation.

Comment: Try: `response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=params)` Based on their docs: https://api.bol.com/retailer/public//Retailer-API/demo/v9-OFFERS.html#_create_an_offer_export_csv_file

Comment: Works. Feeling stupid. Is it that way because "Content-Type" -> JSON? I can't find a explicit statement on that.

Comment: When you see `POST`, then you have to actually post some data (and that's what `json=` parameter is for). And based on content-type the server accept data in Json format. I'll post an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on their documentation (found [here](https://api.bol.com/retailer/public//Retailer-API/demo/v9-OFFERS.html#_create_an_offer_export_csv_file)) the server accepts data in Json format. So the correct code should look like:

```py
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.retailer.V9+json',
    "Content-Type": 'application/vnd.retailer.V9+json',
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + f"{access_token}"
}
params = {
    "format": "CSV",
}

url = "https://api.bol.com/retailer/offers/export"
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=params)  # <-- note the json= parameter
```